# Changing the date format while fetching from database in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Need to change the date format to mm-dd-yyyy while fetching from database in some forms it is displaying in the same format in some files it is displaying in yyyy-mm-dd format.

While doing echo in the function it is displaying in the format ( yyyy-mm-dd)

```
<?php echo $oppointArr['dob'];?>
```

But while fetching the same data in input type date it is displaying correctly.

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $oppointArr['dob'];?>" name="dob" id="dob" >
```

Comment: _“But while fetching the same data in input type date it is displaying correctly.”_ - the keyword here is _display_. What your script output at this position, is still yyyy-mm-dd format - simply because a date input field _requires_ that format when setting a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the date function of the PHP

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
date('mm-dd-yyyy',strtotime($oppointArr['dob'])
```